# Confirmation message in WFFM in Sitecore

Tags: wffm

We are using Web Form for Marketers in `Sitecore 7.2 with MVC`. We are using one field of the form to show thank you message.

`<p> Thanks for Submission </p>
<p> You have successfully subscribed to our news letter</p>`

But it shows a message like follows

> <div class="wfm-thank-you"> <p>Thanks For
>   Submission</p> <p>You have successfully subscribed to our
>   newsletter</p> <p>

It shows HTML tags with a message.

Anu suggestion will be helpful.

Answer (score 7):

I already had the same issue and following how you I solved it:

Navigate to the following file path:

..\Website\Views\Form\EditorTemplates\FormModel.cshtml

Update the following lines:

```
if (Model.SuccessSubmit)
{
    @Html.Raw(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.SuccessMessage) ? Model.SuccessMessage : Translate.Text("Default success message."))
    //@Html.Encode(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.SuccessMessage) ? Model.SuccessMessage : Translate.Text("Default success message."))
    return;
}
```

Comment: Nice catch @Mohammed :)

Answer (score 2):

WFFM does not provide this functionality by default in this version. It allows outputting only plain text. I would suggest to use 'Redirect' success form action.